# How to populate a document inside an array inside another document?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema, populate

Sorry if title looks complicated... I couldn't think of a better way to describing it.

My real case situation matches the following Schemes:

**Collection1**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id:         mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name:        { type: String, required: [true, 'Name is required.'] },
  quantity:    { type: Number, required: [true, 'Quantity is required.'] },
  collection2: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Collection2' }
}, { _id : false });

const collection1Schema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id:          mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name:         { type: String, required: [true, 'Name is required.'] },
  imagePath:    { type: String, required: [true, 'Image is required.'] },
  items:        [itemSchema]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Collection1', collection1Schema);
```

Note: **itemsSchema** is inside the collection1 file (and having **no** declared **_id**'s) because they only exist for the Collection1 model (considering "quantity" and other fields I removed for simplification). This itemsScheme is not needed elsewhere as another collection.

**Collection2**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const collection2Schema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id:    mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name:   { type: String, required: [true, 'Name is required.'], unique: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Collection2', collection2Schema );
```

Note: Other properties (such as 'imagePath') were removed for simplification.

Now, this is the query I am trying to run:

```
Collection1.find()
 .populate({
   path: 'items',
   populate: {
     path: 'collection2', model: 'Collection2'
   }
 })
 .then(...)
 .catch(...);
```

And this is the error message I am getting when I run it:

```
Error fetching collection1:  Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{
  name: 'an item name',
  quantity: 750
}" at path "_id" for model "Collection1"
```

The exact same error happens if I just run:

```
Collection1.find()
 .populate('items')
 .then(...)
 .catch(...);
```

Maybe I cannot run `.populate('items')` because it has no declared model. If this is the case, how can I populate collection2 while querying collection1? Again, I cannot consider storing items in a separated collection.

But if I run:

```
Collection1.find()
 .populate('collection2')
 .then(...)
 .catch(...);
```

I get the items, no errors, but it doesn't populate collection2. Well, it makes sense for the items because they're just an array of a block of properties inside collection1. But what about populating collection2?

Collection2 already has a few documents added, all with their **_id**s and other fields well filled. In the controller, I set `_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`, while creating a new document for both cases, Collection1 and Collection2.

**In the front-end**, I create a new document for Collection1, I add items, each item with a document from Collection2, and I save everything with no errors. I also confirmed everything is been properly saved (collection1 has list of items and each item an _id reference to collection2). The only problem is populating collection2 inside this array.

I have already tried restructuring everything with **_id**s (including **itemScheme**) and dropping all collections to test it again but no success.

I have been stuck with this problem for about three days now.

Is there any special property I should be setting for **populate** to make it work for this specific structure?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
populate('items')
```

This will not work as **item** is not a model.

What you want is following:

```
Collection1.find()
 .populate('items.collection2')
 .then(...)
 .catch(...);
```

This will populate **collection2** in all the array elements

Comment: Working like a charm! ^^